# How to customize BuddyPress Notification triggers?

Tags: buddypress

Trying to figure out where in the BP code to look for hooks or filters so that I can control what triggers notifications.

On the BP site it says "By default, notifications are created as soon as one of the following things happen:"

And then there is a huge list of notification triggers. But I want to turn them on and off as I see fit. Anyone have experience customizing BP? Curious how one goes about this sort of BP customization.

thanks,
Brian

Comment: I'd suggest https://buddypress.org/support/ 3rd party plugins are off topic here so your post might get flagged

Comment: The buddypress support forum isn't that impressive if you know what I mean... Nothing beats stackexchange for really in depth questions/answers. I think I will try intercepting the notification send via a hook and just not let it send.